# In an App Engine NDB model, do references to related models need to be explicitly cached to minimize query costs and optimize performance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The [App Engine documentation on NDB caching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) indicates that caching is enabled by default:

> NDB automatically caches data that it writes or reads (unless an application configures it not to).

I hope this means that I can rely on it to manage key-related models in a cost-effective and performant way. Here's a simple example involving two models with a one-to-many relationship.

A user model (has many comments):

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name                    = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email                   = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    def comments(self, limit=25):
        return UserComment.query(UserComment.user_key == self.key) \
                          .order(-UserComment.created_at) \
                          .fetch(limit)
```

A comment model (each comment belongs to a user):

```
class UserComment(ndb.Model):
    user_key                = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
    text                    = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    created_at              = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def user(self):
        return self.user_key.get()
```

And a template where a comment is displayed and includes two references to `comment.user`:

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="body">
    {{ comment.text }}
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    by {{ comment.user.name }} ({{ comment.user.email }})
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this a sane pattern? Will each reference to `comment.user.name` and `comment.user.email` incur a separate [query cost](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls) or can the automatic NDB cache be trusted to avoid or minimize this?

Similarly, with the `User.comments` method, can automated caching be trusted minimize costs? Or is it advisable to add code that explicitly uses memcache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDB caching covers entities themselves. From the doc you mentioned:

> NDB automatically caches data that it writes or reads (unless an
>   application configures it not to). Reading from cache is faster than
>   reading from the Datastore.

This means that by default you shouldn't need to bother with manual handling of caching for direct key/property lookups like `comment.user.name` and `comment.user.email`, ndb will take care of that.

However queries are a different story - there is no way to know if the data returned by a query remains the valid response for the same query repeated at a later time - additional data may have been created in the meantime. Caching query results is the very first memcache use mentioned in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_When_to_use_a_memory_cache):

> One use of a memory cache is to speed up common datastore queries. If
>   many requests make the same query with the same parameters, and
>   changes to the results do not need to appear on the web site right
>   away, the app can cache the results in the memcache. Subsequent
>   requests can check the memcache, and only perform the datastore query
>   if the results are absent or expired. Session data, user preferences,
>   and any other queries performed on most pages of a site are good
>   candidates for caching.

In other words you should attempt to manually cache things like `User.comments` which rely on queries for their return value.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to UserComment.user() will perform a get from the datastore. But, a second call self.user_key.get() from the same key will return the cached entity.

But anyway... this is a poor design because you are performing separate RPC calls to the datastore instead of retrieving all the User entities at once with get_multi().

Comment: If I were to redesign, I imagine I'd denormalize the comment model to capture the relevant user fields.